# Communication between view and model through multiple controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

In iOS, I treat viewcontroller as controller.
As there are multiple subviews(forms) in my viewcontroller, I have created custom views and added them on viewcontroller's view. I have used MVC so that data on view gets updated onto model through controller.
As an example,  [image]

ViewController's view is added on MainViewController but all the actions on this view will be done by ViewControllerOne.Despite MainViewController has view of ViewControllerOne, it can not communicate with the subviews of ViewControllerOne. When **next** is clicked in ViewOne, save method of viewControllerOne will be executed by delegate, in this way **save** button-action works.

It works for many viewcontrollers.

Now, the **Save** button only is moved onto MainViewController's view but all functionality should not be changed. For example,
[image] 
As MainViewController can not access viewOne and viewTwo of ViewControllerOne, save(task,date) and saveDescription(desc, date) can not be executed so that data will not be saved on model. But to update model, the flow of events should go through, mainViewController->ViewControllerOne->ViewOne->ViewControllerOne(delegate)->Model.

It seems more complicated.
Please suggest me.

Comment: The data should not belong to the views.  As soon as it's entered it should be held by the controller (or a temporary Task-type object within the controller).  Your save operation would not reference any view, only controllers.

Comment: Thanks, here view just holds data in textfields and other views.